# How to make style library configurable

Tags: reactjs, twitter-bootstrap, jsp, configuration, components

I'm working with jsps in my workplace. Pages were built using bootstrap2. Though new versions of bootstrap and other frameworks came out, I'm stuck with bootstrap2 as we have hundreds of pages using it.

How do I make the style configurable, in the sense, the configuration should give me the freedom to choose the framework, etc. So going forward I can choose what to be used for new pages

Answer (score 0):

I can relate to your problem as this is the case with many "old" products in the market. They could be built with jQuery, plain js or other tools that considered "old" in today's market.

I assume you could not refactor your whole app as you are saying there hundreds of pages. Some options to consider and to set pros and cons for each with management and product teams.

First, you need to decide your technology you want to use and how.

1. You can use small bits of react/vue.js/other to inject into your existing pages
2. you can create full pages from newer technologies and slowly replace older pages in the app one by one
3. start a full rewrite of the app (hard to sell to management)

I did all three options in my projects but you need to decide with your own team.

Now I'll elaborate on what you can do for each of the options:

1. I use react so can't recommend other libraries, but this is what I used:
   https://github.com/rstacruz/remount

You build react components and then you can use them as HTML snippets in your existing code.

2. You create another app in whatever new language you want and start building out exiting pages one by one. With each new page, you build you link the old app to them.
3. This is the easiest one to start but the longest one to achieve. But straightforward of what you need to do.

Answer (score 0):

To make the styles configurable, you can add another stlye.css file underneath the bootstrap2 css file. In that style.css file(name it anything you want, can be bootstrap2_override.css) you can add any styles as well as override bootstrap2's framework styles.

The downside to this is that you are now adding another css file with more CSS just to override bootstrap2 styles.